# How to join to sum up values 30 days after certain date from first dataset?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a dataset which contains information about account creation date.

| user_id | created_date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 7.05.2021 |
| 2 | 13.06.2022 |

And another one which have information about deposits:

| user_id | funding_date | amount_usd |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 9.05.2021 | 200 |
| 1 | 11.05.2021 | 300 |
| 2 | 10.07.2022 | 50 |
| 2 | 11.07.2022 | 100 |

And I would like to join first dataset with second to sum up all deposits 30 days after created_date from first dataset. Is it possible to do it with join or i have to firstly aggregate data in the second one and then join by specific date?

Comment: Pleas add tag for database you use. You can just do a regular join and use an expression in your sum to only select the values of interest.  mysql support if(), otherwise you use a case statement.

Comment: It is redshift. But this solution will not duplicate all rows from first dataset?

Comment: I have never used redshift so others will have to help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by myself by using join:

```sql
SELECT t1.user_id, t1.created_date, SUM(amount_usd) as deposits_30days
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON
t1.user_id = t2.user_id and DATEDIFF(day, t1.created_date, t2.funding_date) BETWEEN 0 AND 30
GROUP BY 1,2
```